# MySQL go through all rows and number them

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I added a column in the table for the numbering. I would like to go through all the rows in the table and number them from 1 onwards. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `AUTO_INCREMENT`. It will automatically update your existing rows and all future rows.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE id id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```